# Create MSOutlook Com-Object and make it visible

Tags: powershell, outlook, com

I would like to start MS Outlook for automation and make it visible. I'm typing command:

```
(new-object -com Outlook.Application).GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder("olFolderInbox").GetExplorer().Display()
```

Which throws error:

```
Exception setting "GetDefaultFolder": Cannot convert the "olFolderInbox" value of type "string" to type "Object".
At line:1 char:1
+ (new-object -com Outlook.Application).GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefault ...
```

This doesn't work too:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
$Outlook.visible = $True
```

Spoiler! This works:

```
(new-object -com Outlook.Application).GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).GetExplorer().Display()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method takes the type of default folder to return represented by the [OlDefaultFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) enumeration (numeric values).

Comment: this one works: (new-object -com Outlook.Application).GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).GetExplorer().Display()